# The way to execute http callout from apex

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, future

I'm a new in integration and I try to make a simple integration, but i'm stuck.

Scenario is simple:
When record updates or creates, need to pass record data to external system. So I create a class and a trigger to run that class:

```
trigger AccTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

    for(Account acc: Trigger.new){
        if(Trigger.IsInsert && Trigger.IsAfter){;
            integration.POST(acc.id);
        }
        if(Trigger.IsUpdate && Trigger.IsAfter){;
            integration.POST(acc.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
global with sharing class integration {

    //@InvocableMethod
    @future(callout=true)
    global static void POST(Id AccountId) {
        String secret = 'MySecret';

        Blob requestBlob = Blob.valueOf(secret);
        Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', requestBlob);
        //Need to convert into hex to generate the equivalent of md5(string) method of PHP.
        String requestSignature = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hash);

        //Generate json body
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('salesforceId', AccountId);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        String jsonS = gen.getAsString();
        System.debug('jsonMaterials='+jsonS);

        //Send call out to adminka
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('MyEndPoint');
        request.setHeader('X-API-KEY', requestSignature);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setbody(jsonS);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 201) {
            system.debug('Hooray!');
        } else {
            system.debug('Error='+response.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

All works great, but think that the use of future method is not fits my requirements. In a 24 hours it may be of thousands of records that have been updated.

Can anybody tells how to call post method on update without hitting any limits for a lot of dml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed 250k future calls per day (combined with other things such as QUeueable, Batchable, and Schedulable calls); you should probably be okay. However, one thing you should do is batch the calls into groups of 100 for performance reasons.

```
List<List<Id>> batches = new List<List<Id>>();
List<Id> temp;
batches.add(temp = new List<Id>());
for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
  temp.add(record.Id);
  if(temp.size() == 100) {
    batches.add(temp = new List<Id>());
  }
}
if(batches[batches.size()-1].isEmpty()) {
  batches.remove(batches.size()-1);
}
for(List<id> batch: batches) {
  integration.post(batch);
}
```

Adjust your callout code to accept a list of ID values and iterate over all the values.